# Maven profiles and rpm installation

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, rpm

I am using maven profile to differentiate between two environments. A directory structure is created using pom with different user details for each profile

```
    <profiles>
    <profile>
    <id>profile1</id>
    <mapping>
                  <directory>/a/b</directory>
                  <username>user1</username>
                  <groupname>group1</groupname>
                  <sources>
                    <source>
                      <location>../install2.properties</location>
                    </source>
                  </sources>
    </mapping>
    </profile>
    <profile>
    <id>profile2</id>
    <mapping>
                  <directory>/a/b</directory>
                  <username>user2</username>
                  <groupname>group2</groupname>
                  <sources>
                    <source>
                      <location>../install2.properties</location>
                    </source>
                  </sources>
    </mapping>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

During the rpm generation I am using -P option to select the desired profile.

I am not able to see that user/group is getting set based on the profile selected. Can anyone please let me know what is the issue here

Comment: Why do you need to separate between two environments? Does that mean you have to create two diffferent rpm's with different content? Yes than make two executions...so you get rid of profiles...

Comment: @khmarbaise Contents are same. just the access levels are different.

Comment: What do you mean by access levels? Permissions in RPM configuratioN?

Comment: @khmarbaise yes permission levels and user/usergroup owning the file/directory

Comment: That means simply you have to create two different RPM's.. separate executions of rpm-maven-plugin... that will remove the need for profiles...

Comment: @khmarbaise unfortunately we need maintain the same set of code base and automations. Hence having seperate executions are not possible

Comment: Sorry but: `Hence having seperate executions are not possible` this shows that you don't understand Maven nor rpm-maven-plugin. The code base is independant of that.

Comment: Here is an example of multiple executions (for the maven-compiler-plugin) https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/module-info.html but that can be done as well for the rpm-maven-plugin...